# Python script doesn't return anything

Tags: python-2.x

I am trying to run the below script to find a file starting with string `file` and ends with `.txt` and in the specified path.
When run, it doesnt return anything or errors out.

Please suggest on what am I doing wrong here.

```
#!/usr/bin/env

import os

Path = 'C:/'

def find():
    result = []
    for root, dirs,files in os.walk(Path):
        for name in files:
            if name.startswith('file') and name.endswith('.txt'):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result
print (find)
```

I would want the script to run and return the result if file exists or not.

Comment: Return the result to whom, exactly? A result is always returned to the caller. When executing a python script, the caller is the Python Interpreter process itself. The result is probably returned to the Python Interpreter, but it needs not do anything with it.

Comment: BTW, since you're not even calling the function which actually returns the result (`find`), that result will not be returned to the caller, because the function simply isn't executed.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to print the result using `print(find)` it dint help, I am missing something here.

Comment: Try `print(find())`